# I'm following a youtube tutorial. I have added a skin modifier but mine is much fatter than the one in the video. Why?

Tags: modeling, vertices, extrude

this is the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EJRlWitYmo&list=PLnWkebxmBl7Sd5vF2Xt8u6gPELABFy2aC&index=14
I haven't changed any of the settings and I'm using the latest blender version

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your object was very small, you scaled it up but didn't apply the scale? In that case press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*.

You can also change the vertices thickness in *Edit* mode with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> shortcut, or open the *N panel > Item > Mean Radius*:

[image]